# How to convert this postman to curl php?

Tags: php, curl, postman

[image: postmant api]I have Api in Postman but i can't change to curl php. Maybe somebody can help me

I need using this curl code like this, but i don't how to convert the body (value array and file) using curl

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://localhost/api/v1/clients/mobile/user");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, **body data**);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 

    // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman give you the curl code.

On the top right of the screen you got `code` and you select `php cURL`

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

For people i can solved this problem like this. Login your postman and change to your workspace and cek in documentation [image]